# Angular unknow tag generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm doing a select with this code:

Why this option tag is being generated ?

> ```
>  <option value="? string:feminino ?"></option>
> ```

it only happens when:

1. I select a option from the select
2. I make the url updated with the gender
3. Then refresh. (trying to auto select with the option on the url)

html before :

```
  <select id="gender" ng-model="genderMarked" ng-change="updateGender(genderMarked)" >
                            <option value="">Select a gender</option>

                            <option ng-value="collection.slug" ng-repeat="collection in collectionsGender">{{collection.title}}</option>
                        </select>
```

Html after:

```
     <select id="gender" ng-model="genderMarked" ng-change="updateGender(genderMarked)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"><option value="? string:feminino ?"></option>
            <option value="? string:feminino ?"></option>

            <option value="">Select a gender</option>

            <option ng-value="collection.slug" ng-repeat="collection in collectionsGender" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="masculino">Masculino</option>

           <option ng-value="collection.slug" ng-repeat="collection in collectionsGender" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="feminino">Feminino</option>

          <option ng-value="collection.slug" ng-repeat="collection in collectionsGender" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="infantil">Infantil</option>
    </select>
```

And I'm getting the gender already marked from the url (if user refresh the page) with this code:

```
       if($stateParams.genderSlug){
            $scope.genderMarked = $stateParams.genderSlug;
        }else{
            $scope.genderMarked =  '';
        }
```

Comment: Why not `ng-options="collection.slug as collection.title for collection in collectionsGender"` on the `<select>`?

Comment: I'm actually doing this, and I had the same result with this unknown option. I just posted with option to be more clear.

Comment: My guess is the problem lies within `collectionsGender`. How **exactly** is that assigned a value and where does that value come from?

Comment: no way @Phil please post this first comment, so I can mark as the right answer please.

Comment: I'm confused, didn't you say you were already using `ng-options` and it did the same thing?

Comment: I was missing the places on ng-options your comment was right! @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `ng-options` to be much easier to use than repeated `<option>` tags.

Try this

```
<select id="gender" ng-model="genderMarked" ng-change="updateGender(genderMarked)"
        ng-options="collection.slug as collection.title for collection in collectionsGender">
    <option value="">Select a gender</option>
</select>
```